# Автоматическое обновление input

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно сделать автоматическое обновление второго `input'a`?

Т.е допустим я ввожу в первый `input` число и он автоматически, по формуле, высчитывает и выводит мне значение во 2ой. Получилось сделать с простым дивом, но как сделать такой же вывод в `input` не пойму.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=parseFloat(10*this.value)" />
<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Заменить `innerHTML` на `value`.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="document.getElementById('total').value=parseFloat(10*this.value)"/>
<input id="total" value="">
```